# A pip install for jupyter notebook puts its binaries in ~/.local/bin, and then I'm asked to add ~/.local/bin to my PATH. Is it a normal place?

Tags: path, pip

```bash
pip install jupyterlab
pip install notebook
```

sent binaries to `~/.local/bin`:

```bash
ls ~/.local/bin
ipython   jupyter-bundlerextension  jupyter-kernelspec    jupyter-migrate      jupyter-notebook         jupyter-troubleshoot  send2trash
ipython3  jupyter-dejavu            jupyter-lab           jupyter-nbclassic    jupyter-run              jupyter-trust         wsdump
jlpm      jupyter-execute           jupyter-labextension  jupyter-nbconvert    jupyter-server           pybabel
jupyter   jupyter-kernel            jupyter-labhub        jupyter-nbextension  jupyter-serverextension  pyjson5
```

and now I should put `~/.local/bin` in my PATH, according to [After installing with pip, "jupyter: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313876/after-installing-with-pip-jupyter-command-not-found)

But I'm unease about doing so. Is it normal to have some software that installs itself here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing user binaries to `~/.local/bin` conforms to [the XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) and is quite common nowadays:

> User-specific executable files may be stored in `$HOME`/.local/bin. Distributions should ensure this directory shows up in the UNIX `$PATH` environment variable, at an appropriate place.

As you can see from the above, adding `~/.local/bin` to your `PATH` is fine too.

Comment: But aren't you at risk that software after software installed here one script named let's say `start.sh` coming from the software __B__, replaces the `start.sh` script once installed in `./local/bin` folder by the software __A__? If many applications target the same folder?

Comment: Yes, same as with any shared installation directory. But because such shared directories are common practice on Unix-style systems, software developers tend to avoid generic names. Look at what got installed in your case: all the Jupyter executables are prefixed with `jupyter-`.

Comment: I do agree. But it remembers me the times where many software were willing to install themselves on `C:/` root drive, and by the fault of two binaries who shouldn't had the same "too simple" name, but had them, an overwriting happened. I'm not really confident with such kind of install. I prefer those in separate folders, and a specific `$MY_SOFTWARE_A_HOME` in the PATH to search into a dedicated path.

Comment: Unix/Linux isn’t DOS or Windows, the issues you had with `C:` aren’t all that relevant. You asked about `~/.local/bin`, I answered; developers using that path are well aware of the constraints. If you want to know how to configure software to use different paths, feel free to ask a new question.